# Creating a modal window with a Date Picker in C#

Tags: c#, datepicker

I have a C# application in which a function is performed which requires a date. The original specification said that the current date could always be used, but now I have to allow for the user to be able to change the date on demand.

The problem is, this operation executes completely in the background. There is only a menu item which the user clicks to start the process. So I wanted to add, when the user clicks the menu item, a modal window which asks the user for the date to be used, and returns the date entered. I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Do I need to create a form which has only one item on it - a `DatePicker` - and design it to look like a modal window? Or is there an existing modal window class which does exactly this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a modal window built into the framework.

You will have to create a new windows form. Put a datepicker on it. Make its modifier public and do something like this:

```
private void MenuItemClick(objec sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var userEnteredDate = DateTime.MinValue;
   FormWithDate fmNewFormWithDateOnIt = new FormWithDate();
   fmNewFormWithDateOnIt.ShowDialog();
   userEnteredDate = fmNewFormWithDateOnIt.dtTimePickerOnForm.Value;
   fmNewFormWithDateOnIt.Dispose()

   //Do your thing
}
```

**UPDATE:** You could put a button on the form and set its DialogResult = OK and then do the following:

```
if (fmNewFormWithDateOnIt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //Not clicked the red close button on the form
{
       userEnteredDate = fmNewFormWithDateOnIt.dtTimePickerOnForm.Value;
}
```

Comment: But how do I know whether or not the user has changed the date - this seems like it will just grab the value from the form as it's loaded, not wait for the user to click okay...

Comment: This should work fine, it's what I do and I haven't had any problems with the approach.  Except that yours is probably better because I always call Close() instead of Dispose().  Oops!

Comment: @Elie there is `Show()` and `ShowDialog()`.  `ShowDialog()` displays the Window modally.